# Combining rows with mutiple ids to single row involving clob columns

Tags: sql, db2

I am using DB2 database. My problem is this

I have table like this

```
  ID    Msg1(CLob)  Msg2(Clob)  Msg3(Clob)

  1          SomeTex1          NULL       NULL
  1          NULL             SomeText2   NULL
  2          NULL             NULL        NULL
  2          SomeText3        SomeText4   NULL
  3          SomeText5         NULL       NULL
  3           NULL            NULL      SomeText6
```

I need outupt like this

```
  ID         Msg1(CLob)       Msg2(Clob)      Msg3(Clob)
   1         SomeTex1         SomeText2      NULL
   2         SomeText3        SOmeText4      NULL
   3         SomeText5        NULL           Somtext6
```

Basically I need to group by Ids but the same time need to eliminate null values by combining rows.

Comment: table structure is not formatted well, Here is the formatted structure

Comment: What happens if two different rows have a value in the same column?

Comment: How long are the CLOB columns defined? How long is the relevant content? Is it a maximum of two times an ID could show up? Which platform?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse : No, we will not have such a scenario.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher :  COLB values are of size CLOB(40960). It's basically mail body need entire content and we are using DB2 server. ID can show up maximum 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

CLOBs always make things more complicated. Avoing them using VARCHAR instead would have given the option for much simpler solutions.

If LOBs cannot be avoided as your size is really bigger that 32kb this could be one option to solve your problem:

```
with temp as (
select id, msg1, msg2, msg3, 
       row_number() over (partition by id order by 1,2,3,4) as rownum
  from t3
)
select t1.id, 
       coalesce(t1.msg1, t2.msg1, t3.msg1) as msg1,
       coalesce(t1.msg2, t2.msg2, t3.msg2) as msg2,
       coalesce(t1.msg3, t2.msg3, t3.msg3) as msg3
 from temp t1 
 left join temp t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.rownum = 1 and t2.rownum=2
 left join temp t3 on t1.id = t3.id and t1.rownum = 1 and t3.rownum=3
where t1.rownum = 1
```

Comment: 1] You don't need to use `id` in the `ORDER BY`, given that's your partition.  2] You actually don't need the `ORDER BY` at all in this case, given `COALESCE`.  It's really only useful here for uniquing rows, you can't use it to say which columns are filled.  3] Given the limited running scope, it may be appropriate (and faster) to use `RID` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` here.  4] The `LEFT JOIN`s don't need the `AND t1.rownum = 1` condition (because of the `WHERE`).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: excellent points - appreciated. But I am curious how you would use the RID function for the join and WHERE condition ...

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher : Here we  need to have no temp tables equal to no of clob columns, right?

Comment: @ashokkumar-angadi I am not sure if I understand your question right... My SQL uses only a common table expression and no materialized temp table - the table temp is built inside the SQL - no prerequisites so...

Comment: Argh, you're right, I think I tossed my brain out a little.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL solves the problem:

```
select
    f1,
    listagg( nvl2(f2,f2,' ')) as f2,
    listagg( nvl2(f3,f3,' ')) as f3,
    listagg( nvl2(f4,f4,' ')) as f4
from t0
group by f1
```

Using DB2 LUW V10.5.3:

With the following SQL script providing details:

```
connect to pocdb;

drop table t0;
create table t0 (
    f1 integer,
    --f2 char(100),
    --f3 char(100),
    --f4 char(100)
    f2      clob,
    f3      clob,
    f4      clob
)
;

insert into t0(f1,f2) values (1,'msg - f2 - key 1');
insert into t0(f1,f3) values (1,'msg - f3 - key 1');
insert into t0(f1,f4) values (1,'msg - f4 - key 1');

insert into t0(f1,f2) values (2,'msg - f2 - key 2');
insert into t0(f1,f3) values (2,'msg - f3 - key 2');
insert into t0(f1,f4) values (2,'msg - f4 - key 2');

insert into t0(f1,f2) values (3,'msg - f2 - key 3');
insert into t0(f1,f3) values (3,'msg - f3 - key 3');

insert into t0(f1,f2) values (4,'msg - f2 - key 4');
insert into t0(f1,f4) values (4,'msg - f4 - key 4');

insert into t0(f1,f2) values (5,'msg - f2 - key 5');

insert into t0(f1,f3) values (6,'msg - f3 - key 6');
insert into t0(f1,f4) values (6,'msg - f4 - key 6');

export to /tmp/t0.unl of del
select
    f1,
    listagg( nvl2(f2,f2,' ')) as f2,
    listagg( nvl2(f3,f3,' ')) as f3,
    listagg( nvl2(f4,f4,' ')) as f4
from t0
group by f1
;

connect reset;
terminate;
```

Running the command:
    db2 -tvf t0.sql > t0.out 2>&1

The *t0.out* results create are:

```
cat t0.out

connect to pocdb

  Database Connection Information

Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.3
SQL authorization ID   = DB2INST1
Local database alias   = POCDB


drop table t0
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

create table t0 ( f1 integer, f2        clob, f3        clob, f4        clob )
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f2) values (1,'msg - f2 - key 1')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f3) values (1,'msg - f3 - key 1')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f4) values (1,'msg - f4 - key 1')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f2) values (2,'msg - f2 - key 2')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f3) values (2,'msg - f3 - key 2')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f4) values (2,'msg - f4 - key 2')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f2) values (3,'msg - f2 - key 3')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f3) values (3,'msg - f3 - key 3')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f2) values (4,'msg - f2 - key 4')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f4) values (4,'msg - f4 - key 4')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f2) values (5,'msg - f2 - key 5')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f3) values (6,'msg - f3 - key 6')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

insert into t0(f1,f4) values (6,'msg - f4 - key 6')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

export to /tmp/t0.unl of del select f1, listagg( nvl2(f2,f2,' ')) as f2,
   listagg( nvl2(f3,f3,' ')) as f3, listagg( nvl2(f4,f4,' ')) as f4 
   from t0 group by f1
SQL3104N  The Export utility is beginning to export data to file
"/tmp/t0.unl".

SQL3105N  The Export utility has finished exporting "6" rows.


Number of rows exported: 6


connect reset
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

terminate
DB20000I  The TERMINATE command completed successfully.
```

The *export* results created are:

```
cat /tmp/t0.unl

1,"msg - f2 - key 1  "," msg - f3 - key 1 ","  msg - f4 - key 1"
2,"msg - f2 - key 2  "," msg - f3 - key 2 ","  msg - f4 - key 2"
3,"msg - f2 - key 3 "," msg - f3 - key 3","  "
4,"msg - f2 - key 4 ","  "," msg - f4 - key 4"
5,"msg - f2 - key 5"," "," "
6,"  ","msg - f3 - key 6 "," msg - f4 - key 6"
```